# move a stereoscopic video on the screen

Tags: python, video, 3d, move

I would like to move a (stereoscopic) video on a computer screen automatically. Think of the video as the ball in a Pong game. The problem is that it should be a stereoscopic 3D video. So the video size itself is kind of small. I did this kind of movements with pictures or drawing object, but I don't know how to do it with video material!

Does somebody know how I can do this? I already searched for video tools in python like pygame or pyglet. I have an external player Bino 3d which can open the desired video. But how can I make it move around the screen?
Or is there a tool in other programming languages like c/c++ or Matlab which can help?
By the way, the program will be on a Linux OS.

I'll be grateful for any help or hints!

Anna

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to use a decent video client (`mplayer`, `vlc`).  They can present the video in lots of ways, hopefully your stereoscopic issue can be solved by them.

Then I would let the client present a single window (not fullscreen) which I then would move around using window manager controls.

If you must not have window decorations around the video or if the output shall be a specific window, I think `mplayer` at least can be told to use an existing window to perform the output in.  Maybe that's an approach then.